# Pickerviews and Tableviews

Tags: iphone

Can I use just one controller to have a Tableview (bottom half of the screen) shared with a Pickerview (top half of the screen)?

Also, is the Tableview the best way to implement an eight row by two column view used for display purposes only, or is there a better - easier - way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes
The pickerview uses a delegate protocol, so get your tableview controller to conform to the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol: info here http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html

Tableview sounds like the right way to do it.  The wrong way would be to layout 2x8 controls onto a scrollview (IMHO). Once you have the hang of a table view, its really easy to use - ditto the pickerview delegates.